# Where is the FAQ?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, help-center, tour

I found [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213726/betting-algorithm) that I thought might be more of a statistics question, so I thought I would head over to stats.SE to check out the FAQ to see what's on-topic.

There's no obvious link to a FAQ, but there is a link to a "tour", and that has [a link to the FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). Unfortunately, the FAQ page just redirects you to the tour.

While I would hope that the FAQ (or criteria for "on-topic" questions) would be readily available from the help page of the site, at the very least the link for it on the tour should be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

For guys arriving here now, the hyperlinks on the Cross Validated (CV) tour page were fixed (as stated by cardinal).

Where is the FAQ?

1. [CV's Tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). For quick comprehension about how the Stack Exchange sites work.
2. [CV's Help Center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help). This is the FAQ.
3. [What is Meta?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) This will help understanding what the meta site is for and how it works.
4. Posts on CV meta tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). These posts are complementary guidelines developed by our community.